# Different definitions of Exponential Time Hypothesis

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, satisfiability

I am reading basics of [Exponential Time Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) (ETH). There are two statements for it:

**Statement 1**
There exists no $2^{o(n)}$ algorithm for $3$-SAT, where $n$ is the number of variables.

**Statement 2**
If $\delta_q$ ($q \ge 3$) is the infimum of set of constants $c$ for which there exists an algorithm for solving $q$-SAT (each clause has $\le q$ literals) in time $\mathcal{O}^{\text{*}}(2^{cn})$ (here $\mathcal{O}^{\text{*}}(.)$ supresses any non-exponential part of the running time). Then $\delta_q > 0$.

I can see that if $1$ holds, then so does $2$. But why is it so that $2$ may/may not imply $1$ ?
If $2$ holds then would it be wrong to argue that $\delta_3 > 0$. And as $\delta_{i+1} \ge\delta_i$ ($i \ge 3$), because increasing upper bound on number of literals in each clause can only make the problem *more* difficult to solve, it will imply $1$.

Comment: Strong ETH states that $\delta_q \to 1$.

Comment: Also, the sequence $\delta_q$ is (possibly weakly) *increasing*. If you can solve $(k+1)$-SAT, then you can use the same algorithm to solve $k$-SAT using a single new dummy variable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I changed the wording. The two statements for ETH are mentioned here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis (have added same link in question as well)

Comment: Wikipedia mentions an explanation as well as a relevant citation. Have you consulted Flum & Grohe (2006)?